# How to style CSS to display element as column style

Tags: css

How do you write CSS to display elements like `ul` or `div` in a column style

I would like my elements to look something like this

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

without having to have three separate `div` tags for three columns.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking at achieving?

http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/

Comment: Hi, Charlie
thanks for your answer but it's css3, maybe it's not cross browsers

Comment: I think it is css3 only, did you see an example in previous css versions?

Comment: i have a solution but i dont wanna use it because it based on divs tag to make column and then we put more divs or ul tag into parent divs. I wanna find another solution to prevent nested divs